# PHP: PGSQL driver and AutoCommit?

Tags: php, postgresql, transactions, autocommit

I use pg_connect, and pg_query in a project.
But I'm really not sure that is pg_connect using AutoCommit mode or not?

It is important question, because I need to write some block under transaction, and if one of the statements would be ignored by the server, the database would be inconsistent...

Also interesting question that do pg_query a commit after execution?

For example:

```
pg_query('begin; update table1...; update table2...; commit');
```

is same as

```
pg_query('begin;');
pg_query('update table1...;');
pg_query('update table2...;');
pg_query('commit');
```

and is the

```
pg_query('begin; update table1...; update table2...; commit');
```

working in AutoCommit mode, so begin and commit is nevertheless?

Thanks for your help:
   dd

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, there is no AutoCommit mode in PostgreSQL and the pg_* functions of the PHP API do not try to emulate one.

pg_query's [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query.php) says

> When multiple statements are passed to the function, they are
>   automatically executed as one transaction, unless there are explicit
>   BEGIN/COMMIT commands included in the query string

So it guarantees that `pg_query("UPDATE1 ..; UPDATE2...")` executes in one transaction and has an all-or-nothing effect on the data.

The sequence

```
pg_query("BEGIN");
pg_query("UPDATE1...");
pg_query("UPDATE2..");
pg_query("COMMIT");
```

is equivalent to `pg_query("UPDATE1 ..; UPDATE2...")` with regard to data integrity (half-finished state cannot happen).

As for the note "unless there are explicit BEGIN/COMMIT...", it is relevant only if these are not at the beginning and end of the entire chain of SQL statements.
That is, `pg_query("BEGIN; update1; update2; COMMIT;");` is equivalent to `pg_query("update1; update2;")` but (obviously) not equivalent to `pg_query("update1; COMMIT; update2;")`

Comment: What about this, this a new feature? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ecpg-sql-set-autocommit.html

Comment: @Eddified: no, this is old. [ECPG](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ecpg.html) implicitly opens transactions and it's called "autcommit off". See [Managing Transactions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ecpg-commands.html#ECPG-TRANSACTIONS)

Comment: @DanielVérité Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70542165/commit-the-transaction-at-last-stored-procedure-in-postgresql