# PHP script not inserting into pg database

Tags: php, postgresql

I am writing a basic PHP registration script with the following database:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS authentication;
CREATE TABLE authentication (
    userID SERIAL UNIQUE REFERENCES users(userID),
    eMail TEXT PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES users(eMail),
    passwordSalt TEXT,
    hashedSalt TEXT,
    saltText TEXT,
    securityAnswer1 TEXT,
    securityAnswer2 TEXT, 
    securityAnswer3 TEXT
);
```

and the following registration script:

```
<?php
  include 'https.php';

  //Create a connection to the database. If the connection fails, kill the
  //process and issue an error message
  $conn = pg_connect("host=localhost user=myusername password=mypassword dbname=mydatabase");
  if (!$conn) {
    die("Failed to connect to database.");
  }

  //If the register button is pressed..
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //Check to make sure password+confirmation match. If not, error out.
    if ($_POST['password'] != $_POST['confirm-password']) {
      echo 'ERROR: passwords do not match<br />';
      echo 'Return to <a href="registration.php">registration</a> page.<br />';
      break;
    }

    //Then check to make sure the username doesn't already exist in the DB.
    $result = pg_prepare($conn, "duplicateUser", 'SELECT username FROM mydatabase.users WHERE username = $1');
    $result = pg_execute($conn, "duplicateUser", array($_POST['username']));
    $row = pg_fetch_assoc($result);

    //If it already exists, set match to true.
    foreach ($row as $res) {
      if ($res == $_POST['username'])
        $match = true;
    }

    //If match is true, error out.
    if ($match == true) {
      echo 'ERROR: username already in use<br />';
      echo 'Return to <a href="registration.php">registration</a> page.<br />';
      $match = false;
      break;
    }
  }
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Registration page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method='POST' action='registration.php'>
Username (e-mail): <input type='text' name='username' /><br />
Password: <input type='password' name='password' /><br />
Confirm password: <input type='password' name='confirm-password' /><br />
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Register' /><br />
</form>
Return to <a href='index.php'>login</a> page.<br />

</body>
</html>

<?php

  //If the registration button is pressed..
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //Take the username and password, salt the password using an SHA1
    //encryption of a random number, concatenate the password to the
    //beginning of the salt, then save the SHA1 of that concatenation
    //as the hashed and salted password.
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $confirmusername = $_POST['confirm-username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $confirmpassword = $_POST['confirm-password'];
    if ($username != $confirmusername)
        echo "Please make sure your username is consistent.";
    if ($password != $confirmpassword)
        echo "Please make sure your passwords match.";

    $salt = sha1(rand());
    $saltedPass = $password.$salt;
    $hashedSalt = sha1($saltedPass);

    //Store the username, hashed+salted password, and salt in the
    //authentication table.
    $result = pg_prepare($conn, "authentication", 'INSERT INTO mydatabase.authentication VALUES ($1, $2, $3)');
    $result = pg_execute($conn, "authentication", array($username, $salt, $hashedSalt));

    //Start the session, set the $_SESSION variables loggedin to true and
    //username to the supplied username, then redirect to index.php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    header("Location: index.php");
  }
?>
```

But when I get on PHPpgAdmin, the rows haven't been inserted into the database. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to name the columns you are inserting to. Something like `INSERT INTO mydatabase.authentication (col1, col2, col3) VALUES ($1, $2, $3)`

Answer (score 1):

First thought is that you need to explicitly commit the transaction. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9711570/131226) seems to confirms that there is no autocommit with Postgres.

Comment: I explicitly declared the columns (email, hashedSalt, saltText) in my pg_prepare statement but it's still not posting to the database.

How do I commit the transaction using pg_prepare and pg_execute? I thought pg_execute took care of the commmit?

Comment: `pg_query('COMMIT')`. I imagine `pg_execute('COMMIT')` would work, too. The docs aren't very clear on whether any of the methods autocommit, but it doesn't seem like any of them do.

Comment: It's the concept of autocommit that doesn't exist in postgres. Either you start a transaction and you have to commit it, or you don't start a transaction and obviously you don't have to commit it. The php code above doesn't start any transaction, so no commit is necessary.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. This code is actually from a homework assignment that worked on my school's servers... but I don't know what the issue is here with a RackSpace/Linux infrastructure. No error messages are returned, but nothing is pushed onto the database.

Answer (score 1):

The code should test the result of `pg_prepare` and `pg_execute`, and show or log `pg_last_error()` on error. Otherwise you're in the dark on any problem.

Also, since it connects to a database named `mydatabase` and refers to tables as `mydatabase.tablename`, it can be reasonably suspected that you're applying this MySQL thing of prepending the database name to the table name. It doesn't apply to Postgres. The databases of MySQL are the equivalent of schemas in PostgreSQL.

So unless you have explicitly created a postgres schema named `mydatabase`, try without any prefix:

```
INSERT INTO authentication VALUES ($1, $2, $3)
```

This also apply to the previous `SELECT` that probably fails for the same reason, and it also lacks error checking.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't work either. My issue is that this was working fine on a homework assignment I submitted in class...